# Changes disappear in Visual studio Team Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm using Visual studio 2015 Update 3 with Git as the source control. When I open the solution VS is not showing the changes done in the solution in Team Explorer window even though there were changes. When I close the solution, the Team Explorer window correctly shows the pending changes. Why is this discrepancy happening?

Comment: I noticed VS is quite reluctant to save the solution. You thould issue "save all", to meke it write the solution. Otherwise it happens only when you close or build it.

Comment: Even "save all" or build doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Does this happen with all changed files or only to some? What says the commandline `git status` when VS shows that there are no changes? What if you open some of the problematic files with some other editor (Notepad for example), are there the changes?

Comment: The commandline `git status` correctly shows the modified files. When I open the file in notepad it has the changes.

Comment: A snap shot: if you set `git config core.checkStat default && git config core.ignoreStat false && git config core.fscache false`, and something to refresh index, like maybe `git reset --hard` (warning: this deletes uncommitted changes), would it still happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs due to the `.jfm` file that is automatically created by Visual studio for the SQL server database project in the solution. When this `.jfm` file is committed to source control this issue begins to occur. The issue gets resolved when this `.jfm` file is deleted from source control.